# JS Bigquery example working in chrome/firefox but not in IE?

Tags: google-bigquery

The below example which is given in Google Developers, is working in Chrome/Firfox with out having any issues but not in IE and I am using IE Version#11 (Latest) in windows 8.1.

The chart is not displaying in IE and it a java script error i am getting.![enter image description here][1]

Note:
1. Similar error i am getting when i use Google Developers-JSON example also...to fetch the records from Bigquery and showing in a table...like executing in chrome/firefox but not in IE???
2. If possible Can you please provide and ASP.NET web application example, to connect google BigQuery and showing the Data in GRIDView with C#.NET (NOT WITH ASP.NET MVC)

```
  <html>
<head>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['geochart'] });
</script>
<script>
    // UPDATE TO USE YOUR PROJECT ID AND CLIENT ID
    var project_id = 'XXXXXXXXX';
    var client_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';

    var config = {
        'client_id': client_id,
        //'P12_KEY': 'Keys/ab2c867e84d6d629f0a80595ae14fdbe44492de8 - privatekey.P12',
        //'SERVICE_ACCOUNT' : '87853623787-7lsfbcuu9p3gr9o76opp5fkrvhdf0itk@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
    };

    function runQuery() {
        var request = gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query({
            'projectId': project_id,
            'timeoutMs': '30000',
            'query': 'SELECT state, AVG(mother_age) AS theav FROM [publicdata:samples.natality] WHERE year=2000 AND ever_born=1 GROUP BY state ORDER BY theav DESC;'
        });
        request.execute(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var stateValues = [["State", "Age"]];
            $.each(response.result.rows, function (i, item) {
                var state = item.f[0].v;
                var age = parseFloat(item.f[1].v);
                var stateValue = [state, age];
                stateValues.push(stateValue);
            });
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(stateValues);
            var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
                document.getElementById('map'));
            geochart.draw(data, { width: 556, height: 347, resolution: "provinces", region: "US" });
        });
    }

    function auth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(config, function () {
            gapi.client.load('bigquery', 'v2', runQuery);
            $('#client_initiated').html('BigQuery client initiated');
        });
        $('#auth_button').hide();
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Average Mother Age at First Birth in 2000</h2>
<button id="auth_button" onclick="auth();">Authorize</button>
<button id="query_button" style="display:none;" onclick="runQuery();">Run Query</button>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps because you have console.log() statement and IE doesn't like that.

Comment: Thanks for solution. but now I getting the below error and the program is still not working in IE 'Exception was thrown at line 418, column 127 in https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.hmLUbDKaObI.O/m=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=AItRSTN_XgZKCdnE8RuI46U2eqbYh_3lNQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'timeStamp' of undefined or null reference

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.'